# Dynamic runtime loading of Cocoa Bundles that wrap C++ Code

Tags: xcode, macos, c++11, plugins, objective-c++

I want to use a plugin-like architecture to be able to load modules into a Cocoa-based application. All modules use the same API, but the name and number of modules can vary and is not known when building the application.

Currently, I'm using static libraries, but this requires me to recompile the application every time I add or remove a module. I want to be able to do this dynamically - i.e. restart my Application to update a list of modules added as files.

I'm considering 2 approaches:

1. Use dynamic libraries (.dylib files) and load them at runtime using dlopen() and dlsym()
2. Use Bundles (.bundle files) and load them at runtime using the Cocoa functions

To complicate matters, the modules' code is C++ (legacy code) with an interface like this:

```
// MyModule_API.h 
class MyModule_API {
public:
    static MyModule* create();
    static void destroy(MyModule* m);

    virtual void processMap(std::map<std::string, float>) = 0;
    virtual std::vector<std::string> getNames() = 0;
}
```

One of the current static modules would be defined like this (The module implements the static create/destroy functions and the rest of the API):

```
#include "MyModule_API.h" 
class MyModule : MyModule_API {
public:
    explicit MyModule(std::string param1, std::string param2) : _param1(param1), _param2(param2) { }
    ~MyModule() { };
    // MyModule_API:
    void processMap(std::map<std::string, float>) override { ... }
    std::vector<std::string> getNames() override { return std::vector<std::string({_param1, _param2}); }
private:
    std::string _param1, _param2;
}

MyModule_API* MyModule_API::create() {
    MyModule* m = new MyModule("foo", "bar");        
    //cast to base/API class before returning
    return (MyModule_API*) m;
}

void MyModule_API::destroy(MyModule_API* m) {
    if (m != nullptr) {
        delete m;
    }
}
```

Because of name-mangling in C++, using the dylib approach seems non-feasible, since the application would be unable to locate the symbols by name without hard-coding them.

Therefore, I'm trying to use Objective-C wrappers for the modules and then importing them as NSBundles from Resources/Plugins folder in the .app.

```
// MyModule_ObjC.h
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#include "MyModule_API.h"
@interface MyModule_ObjC : NSObject {
    MyModule_API* _myModule;
}
- (id) init;
- (void) dealloc;
- (MyModule_API*) getMyModule;
@end


// MyModule_ObjC.mm
#import "MyModule_ObjC"
@implementation MyModule_ObjC
- (id)init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        _myModule = MyModule_API::create();
    }
    return self;
}
- (void)dealloc {
    MyModule_API::destroy(_myModule);
}
- (MyModule_API*) getMyModule {
    return _myModule;
}
@end
```

With this, I can successfully build a .bundle file.
I then try to import this bundle into a Cocoa-based test app:

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
#import <mach-o/dyld.h>
#import "MyModule_ObjC.h"
#include "MyModule_API.h"

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {    
    NSBundle *appBundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
    NSArray *bundlePaths = [appBundle pathsForResourcesOfType:@"bundle" inDirectory:@"PlugIns"];
    for (id bundlePath in bundlePaths) {
        NSBundle* bundle;
        bundle = [NSBundle bundleWithPath:bundlePath];
        [bundle load];

        if (bundle) {
            MyModule_ObjC* moduleAPIClass = [bundle principalClass];
            if (moduleAPIClass) {
                id moduleInstance;
                moduleInstance = [[MyModule_ObjC alloc] init];
                if (moduleInstance) {
                    MyModule_API* module = [moduleInstance getMyModule];
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

However, the linker is unable to find "_OBJC_CLASS_$_MyModule_ObjC" ... which makes sense, since the test application project does not include MyModule_ObjC.mm, only .h. If add the .mm, it won't find the static implementations of create/destroy, since the module is not statically linked anymore. However, I want these create/destroy implementations to be in the plugin/bundle.

In principle, is my approach sound?
If not, what approach would you recommend to get this plugin architecture to work?

Thank you in advance and sorry for the long-ish post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you are almost there ;-). The problem lies in the way you treat the plugin interface. At the moment the compiler cannot find the actual symbols because they are unknown at linking time. The solution is rather easy:

Use a protocol instead of your class interface.

```
@protocol MyModule_ObjC <NSObject>

- (MyModule_API*) getMyModule;

@end
```

In your plugins you need to implement this interface and the corresponding principal class.

```
// PluginA.h

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#include "MyModule_ObjC.h"

@interface PluginA : NSObject<MyModule_ObjC>

@end


// PluginA.mm

#import "PluginA.h"

@implementation PluginA {

    @private

    MyModule_API* _myModule;
}

- (id)init {

    self = [super init];

    if (self) {

        _myModule = MyModule_API::create();
    }

    return self;
}

- (void)dealloc {

    MyModule_API::destroy(_myModule);
}

- (MyModule_API*) getMyModule {

    return _myModule;
}

@end
```

In your application, you need to load the plugins against the protocol:

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
#import <mach-o/dyld.h>
#import "MyModule_ObjC.h"
#include "MyModule_API.h"

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {    
    NSBundle *appBundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
    NSArray *bundlePaths = [appBundle pathsForResourcesOfType:@"bundle" inDirectory:@"PlugIns"];
    for (id bundlePath in bundlePaths) {
        NSBundle* bundle;
        bundle = [NSBundle bundleWithPath:bundlePath];
        [bundle load];

        if (bundle) {
            Class moduleAPIClass = [bundle principalClass];
            if (moduleAPIClass && [moduleAPIClass conformsToProtocol:@protocol(MyModule_ObjC)]) {
                id<MyModule_ObjC> moduleInstance;
                moduleInstance = [[moduleAPIClass alloc] init];
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, Jens!  It seems there was really only just this additional level of indirection missing in the Objective-C wrapper :-)

It now links successfully and I'm able to load 2 independent modules.

Comment: That's great! Glad you are up and running.